# Count the words of an array in java

Tags: java, string

I have a list of words e.g : "Moon","Sun","Jupiter","Mars" they are all stored in an array, lets call it "planets"

```
String[] planets = new String[]{"Moon","Sun","Jupiter","Mars"}
```

How do i get the number of words that are stored in the array ?

Comment: Actually `planets` is an array not a string.  Can you rephrase?

Comment: String[] planets = array of string so the array length is your number of words.

Comment: It's an array, you can get the length of the array like this: planets.length

Comment: If you want to ask another question, use another Question.

Comment: The OP is not really wrong about the planets: the sun and moon were two of the original seven planets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those planets are not stored in one String. They are stored in a String array, so there's a String for each planet. If you want to get the number of planets in the `planets` array, just use: `planets.length`.

If you want to build a new array with the first two elements of the array, you can use:

```
   String[] fewPlanets = new String[]{planets[0], planets[1]};
```

You might want to take a look at the [Arrays Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Take into account that there's a typo in the `planets` array declaration in the question. It should be:

```
String[] planets = new String[]{"Moon","Sun","Jupiter","Mars"}
```

If you really had the planets in one string, you could use [`String.split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with a separator to build an array with each of the planets, and use `length` to get the length of the array:

```
String planets = "Moon,Sun,Jupiter,Mars";
String[] planetsArray = planets.split(",");
int numberOfPlanets = planetsArray.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `length = planets.length`

Answer (score 0):

The answer on the first question is: use `planets.length` to count the number of String's in the array.