# how do I ignore/delete values of an array in java

Tags: java, string

I have a list of words , there are 4 words, it cant contain more that 4 its just an example. I want to use just 2 of the words the rest of them should be ignored or deleted e.g :

```
    String planets = "Moon,Sun,Jupiter,Mars";
    String[] planetsArray = planets.split(",");
    int numberOfPlanets = planetsArray.length;
```

the result i get is 4. How do i delete the rest of the words if my list contains more that 2 words ?

Comment: Have you searched for any similar questions here? This search brings up several questions you would be interested in. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delete+from+array+java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7751142/851811), you can use

```
String[] fewPlanets = new String[]{planets[0], planets[1]};
```

Just make sure the `planets` array has 2 elements or more to avoid an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F1.5.0%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Flang%2FArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html&ei=abKWTompDeik4gS5_4DxAw&usg=AFQjCNFaf1u2q7gIWlYsJh4UJMHpD572kg). You can use `length` to check it: `if (planets.length >= 2)`

For a more sophisticated solution, you could also do this using [`System.arrayCopy()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) if you're using Java 1.5 or earlier,

```
int numberOfElements = 2;
String[] fewPlanets = new String[2];
System.arraycopy(planets, 0, fewPlanets, 0, numberOfElements);
```

or [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)) if you're using Java 1.6 or later:

```
int numberOfElements = 2;
String[] fewPlanets = Arrays.copyOf(planets, numberOfElements);
```

Comment: String planets = "Moon,Sun,Jupiter,Mars";
   String[] planetsArray = planets.split(",");
   String[] fewPlanets = new String[]{planetsArray[0], planetsArray[1]}; 

   System.out.println(fewPlanets);
i tryed this but i get some weird stuff if i print it out : [Ljava.lang.String;@67af7a

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String;@67af7a` is what `fewPlanets.toString()` is returning. That is an un unique identifier for the instance. If you want to print the contents of the array, iterate over its elements and print each of them. Something like: `for (int i=0;i<fewPlanets.length;i++){System.out.println(fewPlanets[i]);}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String planets = "Moon,Sun,Jupiter,Mars";
String[] planetsArray = planets.split(",");
if(planetsArray .length > 2){
  String []newArr = new String[2];
  newArr[0]=planetsArray [0];
  newArr[1]=planetsArray [2];
  planetsArray = newArr ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Arrays.asList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) to get a `List` of `String`s from `String[] planetsArray`.

Then use the methods of the [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface -`contains`,`remove`,`add`, ...- to simply do whatever you want on that `List`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select the first 2 planets just copy the array:

```
String[] newPlanetsArray = Arrays.CopyOf(planetsArray, 2);
```

If you need to select 2 specific planets you can apply the following algorithm:

First, create a new array with 2 elements. Then, iterate through the elements in the original array and if the current element is a match add it to the new array (keep track of the current position in the new array to add the next element).

```
String[] newPlanetsArray = new String[2];

for(int i = 0, int j = 0; i < planetsArray.length; i++) {
   if (planetsArray[i].equals("Jupiter") || planetsArray[i].equals("Mars")) {
      newPlanetsArray[j++] = planetsArray[i];
      if (j > 1)
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Arrays.copyOf is only Java 1.6 and later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an idea from [How to find nth occurrence of character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3976616/74057) and avoid reading the remaining values from your comma separated string input. Simply locate the second comma and substring upto there

(Of course if your code snippet is just an example and you do not have a comma separated input, then please ignore this suggestion :)